# AppStore verifyReceipt returning 21007 in sandbox

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, receipt-validation

I am trying to implement in app purchase for my app. I followed some instructions and got stuck in a problem. It says in the documentation to call the sandbox url if status in the response for calling the production url is 21007. But the problem is that I am getting this status in production and also in sandbox. Is there something I am doing wrong? I tried to find the answer on StackOverflow, even though there are some that sound similar, none of the question was the same as mine. I am running my application on a real device through Xcode.

I am doing a POST to https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
with body:

```json
{
    "receipt-data": "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"
}
```

but I receive as response:

```json
{
    "status": 21007
}
```

It is very easy to reproduce using Postman. I get the same response as calling the production url (https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt).

Is there something I am missing? Or maybe it could be a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly a problem from the App Store, see this post in the official Developer Forums:
[21007 Status Code being returned by Sandbox Verify Receipt Endpoint](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/675893)

You can see many developers are having the same issue there.